# Build PHP function to retrieve a variety of mySQL database queries and correctly traverse through multiple tables via their foreign key relationship

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

I am trying to build a robust php function that allows me to traverse over my normalized database.  My mySQL database has 6 tables with the following column names (I am only including the primary and foreign keys, as well as some limited table columns for simplicity) so that you can see how they are related.

**tableA:** 
partID (primary key)

**tableABJunction** 
itemID (foreign key)
partID (foreign key)

**tableB** 
itemID (primary key)
itemName

**sales** 
customerID (foreign key) 
itemID (foreign key)

**partDate** 
itemID (foreign key)

**customer** 
customerID (primary key)
nameFirst
nameLast

When I need to generate a query, such as:  What are the names of the customers that ordered itemID = 12?  I have to first do a query from the sales database for all customerIDs where itemID=12 and then query the customer table to find out their first and last names.  Some times, I may need to perform a query where I have to return data from all 6 tables, based on a query asking for all information pertaining to customer whose name is John Smith.  Is there any easy way to build a function to handle this variety of queries, without having to build a query for every possible type of search?

Currently, my approach is to pass the following to php via AJAX:
web_conditionArray (contains the column name and value of the data provided.  Such as nameFirst => 'John', nameLast => 'Smith'); web_resultArray (contains the table name and the columns that I am requesting:  sales => 'itemID, itemName').

The issue that I am having with this approach is a way to store the relationships between all of the mySQL datatables with their foreign keys so that my php program knows how to link all the tables together to run the correct query to get from the data provided from one table to the data requested in another table.  Any suggestions or a better way to solve this?  I was initially thinking of a doubly linked list but the flow from table to table is not linear given that there is a fork where the tableB links to the sales and partDate tables.

I tried to be as specific as I could in describing this situation without writing a novel; however, please let me know if you need any additional information to refine my question further.

Comment: Looked at how other ORM's do it?  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/

Comment: 2 questions: is `tableABJunction` necessary, and can `orderDate` be absorbed into `sales`?  well structured question btw.  +1 for that.  bottom line tho: if you want speed, handle this logic in php.  if you want rapid development, do it in sql

Comment: @Joe, thanks for taking a look at this questions - Yes, the cross-reference table is necessary since there is a many to many relationship between tableA and tableB.  Regarding the orderDate table, it is actually a typo, it is supposed to be partDate.  it is the date that the part was manufactured.  And it is separated from tableB as the same part is often manufactured multiple times.  There is a date that is also built into the sales table; however, there is no relationship between the two tables.

By handling it in php, are you recommending an array lookup table?

Comment: @ficuscr - I took a look at the doctrine project but it appears to have a lot of additional features that I do not think that I would need to manage the database.  I want the code to run as efficiently and quickly as possible as it is a very large database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your table structure, I imagine it would be possible to construct logic to calculate the relationships between tables, and dynamically construct queries, but it seems to me that that would be far more work than manually constructing queries for your particular database. I'm assuming that your tables have many more fields in them, but that you've only included the most important, and have definitely included all primary and foreign keys.

Based on that, you have only three information objects in your database: Parts, Items and Customers. You should, therefore, not need more than 12 manually constructed queries to make your system work. You just need to ensure that you simplify your queries to work with whole information objects, and use the PHP layer to filter them later.

So, you reduce your query logic to:

```
"Fetch me all [Parts, Items or Customers] (and possibly also all [Parts, Items or Customers]) related to [Part, Item or Custromer] (and possibly [Part, Item or Customer])"
```

This results in the following queries:

- All Customers for a Part
- All Customers for an Item
- All Customers for a Part and an Item
- All Items for a Part
- All Items for a Customer
- All Items for a Part and a Customer
- All Parts for an Item
- All Parts for a Customer
- All Parts for a Customer and an Item
- All Parts and Customers for an Item
- All Customers and Items for a Part
- All Items and Parts for a Customer

(This is the full list of logical relationships - some may not make any sense practically, which makes your life easier)

So, your PHP script needs to perform the following tasks:

- Identify which object(s) are required for the criteria of the query. This is based on the fields supplied.
- Construct a `WHERE` clause for your query which identifies the primary key for the criteria objects from the fields passed.
- Identify which object(s) are required for the result of the query, based on the fields requested.
- Select the query based on the criteria and return objects, and insert the constructed `WHERE` clause.
- Perform the query, extracting all information available about the requested objects
- Filter the results, extracting only the required information
- Return the final results.

Comment: I ultimately accepted this answer, but the number of combinations are much greater than you identified so going completely manual would be too time consuming.  I did end up manually defining each JOIN and then used a lookup function to dynamically build the query.

Answer (score 1):

First, know that my answer will most likely be downvoted to hell (as this methodology is constantly downvoted despite its' correctness).  DBAs want you to believe that just because a complex query *can* be done with a SQL statement that it *should* (like how server-siders think all client-side should be done with server-side or how client-siders think layouts should be done with client-side instead of CSS).  No.  Complex queries are for people sitting at command lines needing to come up with on demand data grabbing for specific, non-routine reasons.  For processing speed, `SELECT`ing, `UPDATE`ing, and `DELETE`ing should always be done off the PK server-side.

It sounds like you have a set of legitimately large tables.

Assuming it's large and speed is the primary concern (and not development time), use only a primary key and no other indexes because the more indexes you have, the more those indexes need to be reindexed by the database when really the comparisons that DBAs would have you do are faster server-side.

The primary key will take some finagling, but it's the most important thing past data types and lengths.  For instance, the non-FK, independent tables like `tableA`, `tableB`, and `customer` should probably have an ai `INT` PK (Generally, remember that computers think in terms of integers), but the ones with multiple FKs should probably have no ai `INT` but instead a composite PK with the less variant `SELECT`ed FK first.  For example, with my site, I store vote totals on links by userID and linkID.  If a user's logged in, they'll need to know how many votes they've placed on a link, so the userID is the one less likely to change, so that's first in my PK on that table.  Counting this on demand database side or server-side was a performance nightmare.

For just a few lines of code, you will ***GREATLY*** improve speed.  Sorting on the PK via php will cut latency by 50%.  Absorbing `JOIN`s into php will decrease the rate of latency spikes.  Having no on demand MySQL calculations will keep your site from becoming paralyzed.

If you step away from the dogma that just because a SQL statement can get you the results that you should use a SQL statement instead of a server-side language (C++ being the fastest), you'll see performance skyrocket.

If you can be more specific with the tables you're trying to obfuscate, I can get more specific, but you probably get the idea.

AJAX has changed the game and forced refocus.  CSS for layouts; js for client-side programming; server-side for...server-side processing; database for storing everything that lasts longer than a moment.

Bring on the downvotes!  LOL

Comment: Joe, thanks for the insight; however, I really want to keep the processing on the database side rather than in php.  The complexity of developing those sorts and joins is very convoluted (this is the route that I originally took).

Comment: @ChrisReedy You'd think, but really, if you're ordering by id, you simply download all ids into a php array and use one of the sorts.  If you're dissolving a join, you simply download the id column and the join column of each table then put the two ids in a new array when they match in a for.